# Posting Processing code onto a website?

Tags: java, html, web, applet, processing

I have exported some Processing code (outputs sensor data to a textbox) to an
applet that includes the .jar and .html files. I have tried to insert this html on a
simple website that I created and the java applet doesn't work. Do I have to somehow
modify the html? I know that the .jar files are already in the same directory and
are referenced appropriately in the exported html code. Is there a better approach
to posting to a website? Thank you

Comment: Could you please post the code? thx

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Tell us what it's supposed to do, what it does instead, what (exact) errors you get.
Post relevant code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible, due to security restrictions on applet communication.

Comment: You think wrong.  Almost anything that requires trust in an applet can be achieved by digitally signing the code, and convincing the end user to trust that code when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you will have to write a small client/server program using sockets.
The idea would be to transmit the the output from your locally running client application to your applet(server) which would receive and display the data.

You could use any language with socket support obviously(Flash, PHP, etc.), but I assume you will want to stick with Java.